# Working with melodia vamp plugin throws error

Tags: python, mp3, midi, librosa

Code:

```
import vamp
import librosa
audio_file=filepath+'ChaitraSairam-Anandaamrutakarshini-Copy.mp3'
audio, sr = librosa.load(audio_file, sr=44100, mono=True)
data = vamp.collect(audio, sr, "mtg-melodia:melodia")
```

I get the below error when I try to run the above code:

```
Vamp::HostExt: Unable to load library "C:\Program Files\Vamp Plugins\mtg-melodia.dll"
Vamp::HostExt: Unable to load library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vamp Plugins\mtg-melodia.dll"
Vamp::HostExt::PluginLoader: No library found in Vamp path for plugin "mtg-melodia:melodia"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\anush\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vamp\collect.py", line 166, in collect
    plugin, step_size, block_size = vamp.load.load_and_configure(data, sample_rate, plugin_key, parameters, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anush\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vamp\load.py", line 83, in load_and_configure
    vampyhost.ADAPT_CHANNEL_COUNT)
TypeError: Failed to load plugin: mtg-melodia:melodia
```

I tried to load melodia with Sonic Visualizer 32 bit and it works in Sonic Visualizer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Melodia plugin from here https://www.upf.edu/web/mtg/melodia (see "Download and installation"). There are options for Windows/Linux/Mac, and this worked for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: The issue was with my python version. I installed 32-bit version of python and it worked. https://code.soundsoftware.ac.uk/projects/vampy-host also confirms it

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was creating the directory that I didn't have but is specified here https://www.upf.edu/web/mtg/melodia (after clicking on "Download and Installation")

```
mkdir /usr/local/lib/vamp
```

Then copying the files there (from a folder 'm' where you've extracted them)

```
sudo cp /home/user/Downloads/m* .
```

Hope this helps!